# How to configure submodules in webpack 4?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, git-submodules

I've created a new app with `create-react-app`, run `npm run eject`.

I added a sub-module under submodule folder: `git submodule add https://github.com/my-library src/submodules`.

In another component (not from submodule) I want to import **directly** from the submoduleI :

```
import { something } from 'my-library'
```

and **not** with relative path like that:

```
import { something } from '../sub-modules/my-library'
```

Where and how should it be configured?

Comment: Check the [module resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths) section in the documentation. I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you use webpack aliases e.g.

```
...
resolve: {
  extensions: [...],
  alias: {
    'my-library': 'path/to/my-library'
  }
},
...
```

Also if you're using typescript - configure the `paths` properly.

Hope this will help!

Comment: And you didn't needed to eject as you could have used [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) to set your specific configurations.